# Exported my logo as PNG from Illustrator, but looks blurry and a little distorted

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, adobe-illustrator

I've made a logo this morning for my website but when I imported it in my website source code, it looked blurry, and I don't know why since my logo is literally a 8256 x 1334px image

[image: :)]

Here is my logo when opened in Illustrator
[image: this is how it it supposed to look]

Comment: Nothing to do with css but the resolution of your image. Once you improve it, it will look normal. When you save it in illustrator, save it for the web

Answer (score 2):

That's waay to much of a file to use on a website. It's probably blurry because you are downscaling it. That resolution is not going to work. If you want it to be really crisp you should export your logo as a .svg file or at a smaller resolution. SVG's are scalable vectors. It will work great in your case. You can find more svg benefits [here](https://blog.tbhcreative.com/2017/06/benefits-of-using-svg.html#:%7E:text=SVG%20stands%20for%20scalable%20vector,choice%20for%20responsive%20web%20design.).